# How can I disable transitions / effect on a nivo slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I have a [Nivo Slider](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider) on my page and I'd like to disable the slider-transition / effect, but there is no option to set the effect-option to 'no', false or something like that. The following options are allowed:

- sliceDown
- sliceDownLeft
- sliceUp
- sliceUpLeft
- sliceUpDown
- sliceUpDownLeft
- fold
- fade
- random
- slideInRight
- slideInLeft
- boxRandom
- boxRain
- boxRainReverse
- boxRainGrow
- boxRainGrowReverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option, but a simple workaround:

Simple choose 'fade' as 'effect' and set 'animSpeed' to 1

Example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      effect: 'fade',
      animSpeed: 1
    });
});
```